# LINQ OrderBy - passing parameter

Tags: .net, linq, func

How to create function and then pass it to OrderBy method?

I want to create OrderBy condition based on string, and then pass it to another method, that would return sorted `Collection<Venue>`

So something like this:

```
string sortby;
var function;
if (sortby == "name")
  // function = (p => p.Name)
else if (sortby == "city")
  // function = (p => p.City)
Collection<Venue> venues = GetVenue(function);
```

etc. `GetVenue` calls somewhere:

```
return venues.OrderBy(function);
```

What type should I make the function and how should I create it?

Comment: Use `IComparable` class for sorting  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: If you hold your mouse over the function call you should see the syntax including the argument type required (assuming Visual Studio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both properties `Name` and `City` of your Venues class are of type `string`, your function should be of type `Func<Venue, string>` for this to work.

```
Func<Venue, string> function;
```

And use it like this:

```
function = new Func<Venue, string>(p => p.Name);
```